# Displaying .vtt subtitles using local files only (ie fixing false cross-origin error)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-video, local, webvtt

I am working on a webpage which serves as a front for a series of documentary videos which will be burned to DVD. We wanted to take advantage of the superior compression of webm videos and the lightweight multi-language solution that .vtt files offer.

However, in Chrome I receive the following error.

> Text track from origin 'file://' has been blocked from loading: Not at same origin as the document, and parent of track element does not have a 'crossorigin' attribute. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Chrome apparently thinks my index.html is a different origin to my .vtt file which is in the exact same local folder. This is supposedly the case for one other browser too (though I can't remember which one).

Seeing as the final product has to be able to run locally on any user's system, the following solutions are **not applicable in my case**:

- Uploading to a web server, which would fix it. (In my case it has to run from a DVD.)
- Setting Chrome to allow file access from files, which is great for if you want to test something locally. (http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/) (But I don't want each DVD user to hack their browser.)
- Fiddling with .htaccess (Works on a webserver, but as far as I understand, these files don't work locally. Sorry I couldn't remember the link for this solution.)
- Baking the subtitles into the videos (not enough space on DVD for all languages).

I am using video.js but would be happy to look at a different framework if it could fix this problem. Also happy to use other types of subtitles (ie .srt) or something that doesn't track tags inside the video tag.

Some solutions mention enabling CORS (http://enable-cors.org/). Does it work on local .vtt files or is it a wild goose chase?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: How about saving a small web server on the DVD? Something like [mongoose](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose).

Comment: Thanks for this great suggestion! I used nwjs and it did the trick! :)

Comment: Nice. You should post an answer on how you set up nw.js. I'd be happy to give you a bounty.